# Python2 Unicode error when using cStringIO

Tags: python, string, list

I want to loop through a list to print out what is stored in the StringIO buffer.  Unfortunately I am encountering a Unicode problem that I can't seem to resolve.

Here is my error:
    'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 65: ordinal not in range(128)

Here is my code:

```
import CStringIO
def get_string(self, dir=None):
    """
    Get all items as tab-delimited string
    """
    ns_sections = self.get_data(dir)
    out = cStringIO.StringIO()
    try:
        for title, data in ns_sections:
            out.write('#\n# %s\n#\n' % title)
            for row in data:
                out.write('\t'.join([str(item) for item in row]))
                out.write('\n')

    except Exception as e:                
        print (e)


    print "HERE"
    contents = out.getvalue()
    out.close()
    return contents
```

I have tried several things but keep getting the same error, here is what I have tried:

```
out.write('\t'.join([str(item).strip() for item in row]))
out.write('\t'.join([str(item)replace(u'\xa0', u' ') for item in row]))
out.write('\t'.join([str(item).replace('\xa0', ' ') for item in row]))
out.write('\t'.join([str(item).replace('\\xa0', ' ') for item in row]))
out.write('\t'.join([str(item).encode('utf-8').strip() for item in row])) 
out.write('\t'.join([str(item).decode('ascii', 'ignore') for item in row]))
```

Here is the problem line:

```
[u'Index_15', u'Sentence here with normal spaces and my problem\xa0which I cannot resolve', 60, u'http://www.nicesite.org/Pathway/#Index_15']
```

Comment: Your code works for any length of `ns_sections`, unless you are producing a very large amount of data (and your program has slowed to a crawl as your OS is struggling to swap out enough memory) you have a different problem altogether, elsewhere.

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you provided us with a small sample (enough to trigger the problem) of the data that gets put in `ns_sections` or edited the code so that wasn't required to run it. As it is we can't really reproduce anything.

Comment: Instead of telling us what it doesn't do when it fails, please describe what it does do.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved my problem.  I was not having any luck with what I tried because I was still using "str" method, incorrect.

I replaced "str" with "unicode" as follows:

```
  out.write('\t'.join([unicode(item).encode('utf-8').strip() for item in row]))
```